# Нет подсказок в Форме в Safari

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Заметил такой баг или не баг, что в safari при нажатии "отправить" с пустыми полями не выводит подсказок типа "Заполните это поле", подсказки стандартные, которые у каждого браузера по своему оформлены. Как исправить данную проблему или что почитать, чтоб поправить ?

```
<form class="callback"
  <p>Оставьте заявку и мы вам перезвоним в течении 15 минут.</p>

  <input type="text" name="Имя" placeholder="Ваше имя..." required>
  <input type="text" name="Телефон" placeholder="Ваш телефон..." required>
  <select name="Услуга">
      <option value disabled selected>Выбрать услугу</option>
      <option>Вариант 1</option>
      <option>Вариант 2</option>
      <option>Вариант 3</option>
      <option>Вариант 4</option>
      <option>Вариант 5</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button button-white">Отправить</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Safari не поддерживает аттрибут `required`, тут только использовать сторонний js плагин для валидации формы, либо делать свою проверку на js

Comment: Хорошо, примерно понял, но получается если я добавлю свои подсказки, будут мои + стандартные, как тогда убрать стандартные ?

Comment: Поддержка http://caniuse.com/#search=required (версии, в которых уже есть поддержка required 10.1 Safari и 10.3 iOS Safari ).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261301/required-attribute-not-work-in-safari-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоватся обычной валидацией форм которая возвращает ложь в противном случае. и да name на Русском давать лучше не надо

```js
$('.callback').on('submit', function(){
if ($('input[name=name]').val() == '' || $('input[name=num]').val() == '') {
alert('Вы не ввели имя или номер телефона')
return false;

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="callback">
  <p>Оставьте заявку и мы вам перезвоним в течении 15 минут.</p>

  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя..." >
  <input type="text" name="num" placeholder="Ваш телефон..." >
  <select name="Услуга">
      <option value disabled selected>Выбрать услугу</option>
      <option>Вариант 1</option>
      <option>Вариант 2</option>
      <option>Вариант 3</option>
      <option>Вариант 4</option>
      <option>Вариант 5</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button button-white">Отправить</button>

</form>
```